# Subnet range notation

Tags: networking, ip

The question is really basic, but I could not find reliable sources after googling for a while.

**What are the standard ways to indicate subnetworks or network segments as a range of IP addresses?**

For instance, the range `1.2.3.0/24` corresponds to the set of IP addresses whose first 3 octets are `1.2.3`. I think this could be written as `1.2.3.0-1.2.3.255`, if the notation `$firstip-$lastip` is valid.

Is this notation valid? Would something like `1.2.3.0-255` be valid as well?

I'm interested to both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: For IPv6, there is a standard, _[RFC 5952, A Recommendation for IPv6 Address Text Representation](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952)_. Basically, you need to represent IPv6 addresses following the standard, but still accept any legitimate IPv6 addresses, even if they don't strictly follow the standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you don't use ranges, you use CIDR notation.

With CIDR, a suffix `/n` is used to indicate the length of the network mask. 10.0.0.0/8 represents 10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255 and so on.

Anything else is not really standard and depends on the context. Essentially, you can use any notation that is not ambiguous. I'd accept a range in the last octet or for the full address but nothing in between (like 1.2.3-5.0-255).

With IPv6 there's little necessity to use 'crooked', non-binary ranges due to the vast address space. Just use subnets indicating the prefix length at all times.